Isekai manga where the main character cooks and dismantles monsters while traveling with a familiar or pet
I am searching for a specific light novel or manga.
One scene I remember involves the main character killing and eating Earth crabs with their partner (familiar/pet). After he cooks and consumes them, he mentions this to the locals in a town/city he visits, and they find the idea revolting.
There's also a possibility that he was fleeing from a kingdom, although I'm not entirely sure about that detail.
The light novel/manga I'm looking for is not Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi (aka Campfire Cooking in Another World with my Absurd Skill).

Are Earth crabs monsters, or is there are mismatch between title and question?

Thank you for the last line, because that's exactly the series that came to mind. :-D Can you explain some of the ways it doesn't match that manga, which features an isekai character with their pet killing and eating crabs? :-D

This might be Souzai Saishuka no Isekai Ryokouki aka A Gatherer's Adventure in Isekai


Takeru Kamishiro is an ordinary middle aged salaryman who was chosen by god to be reincarnated into a fantasy world in the body of a handsome young man in his prime. Takeru sets out to learn more about the world while gathering rare and interesting materials along the way to sell for money which he can use to gather even more materials.

His animal companion is a dragon. In Volume 2, Chapter 12, he kills and eats a giant crab, and in Chapter 13, the townspeople react with disgust (foreshadowed by his appraisal noting that most people find the crabs disgusting).
Found with a search for "cooking" "isekai" "crabs", which led me to this discussion forum topic about Chapter 12.

Yeah, you're correct. It seems my manga memories are jumbled. Is there perhaps another manga that shows the same thing? When I read it, it seemed correct and also not what I was looking for. I just remembered the main character traveling with adventurers to exit the country and either merged it with the campfire story, or perhaps another.

Hmm... Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi is more a match for the traveling with adventurers part, of course, although it's been long enough ago that I don't remember if it involved trying to escape the country.

Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi (aka Campfire Cooking in Another World with my Absurd Skill released 01/2023)  does indeed involve exiting a country with adventurers.  Reading the list of recipes, I mean volumes, I don't see crab on the list nor do I remember it from the videos.  But there were sea monsters in the manga.
